# What is the exact and clear meaning of async/await in Dart language

Tags: dart, asynchronous, async-await

I understand the concept of **asynchronous programming** in Dart using **`Future`**.
By doing this, we try to do things asynchronously in the background and not stop the application.

But I get confused when using `async`/`await` because it contradicts the concept of asynchronous operations! **Because the word `await` causes the program to be temporarily stopped there until that operation is finished**, and this is completely against the concepts of asynchronous programming.

On the other hand, it is said in the Dart language [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#handling-futures)(And I don't understand what it means):

> Note: Although an async function might perform time-consuming
> operations, it doesn’t wait for those operations. Instead, the async
> function executes only until it encounters its first await expression
> (details). Then it returns a Future object, resuming execution only
> after the await expression completes.

In general, why should we use `async`/`await` for asynchronous programming(Although it contradicts its meaning)?

Please explain these concepts clearly and simply.
Thanks.

Comment: I can recommend reading: https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency . Especially the section "Why asynchronous code matters"

Comment: I have read a lot about this and still it's unclear to me that's why I'm asking. Also, some cases were heavy for me, and I request simpler and clearer guidance from others, rather than being referred to a heavier issue! @julemand101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand the concept of asynchronous programming in Dart using Future. By doing this, we try to do things asynchronously in the background and not stop the application.

But it isn't really "in the background".  Dart is cooperative single threaded (if we leave Isolates out of it for a moment).  Only one dart thread is running at a time.

> Because the word await causes the program to be temporarily stopped there until that operation is finished, and this is completely against the concepts of asynchronous programming.

No, it more or less means the opposite of that.  It's more like "we have something that is incomplete and would block us if we waited... let's put a bookmark here, go on to other things, and come back later to see if it's done..."

So unlike "ordinary code" that has to run without yielding, an await is an opportunity to "go to another green thread".

The scheduler can suspend execution in this thread on certain operations, like calling await, returning a Future, calling yield, Future.then, and so on.